How do I use my Canon speedlight in the Godox radio flash system?
I have a Canon 80D and Godox X2T-C and a Canon 580EX speedlite. I need to know how to connect them together to use the 580EX as an off-camera flash. Detailed steps would be appreciated, please.

If you want to control the 580EX via radio, you need to connect a compatible radio receiver to the hot foot of the flash. The only wireless capability the 580EX has on its own is optical wireless control using Canon's optical wireless protocol.
The Godox X1R-C is the only radio receiver not built into a Godox flash that I'm aware of that is compatible with all of Godox's 2.4GHz transmitters, such as your X2T-C.
For detailed instructions, the Godox X2T-C Instruction Manual can be downloaded from the Godox website here. The Instruction Manual for the Godox X1R-C can be downloaded from the Godox website here.
Basically, you attach the X1R-C to the flash and set the flash as if it is attached to the camera's hot shoe. As far as the flash is concerned, the X1R-C is the camera. Then to fully control it from the X2T-C you need to be sure all of the flash's settings are at default values. (That is, Power at 1:1, FEC at +/-0, zoom setting at 'Auto', etc.) Any settings made on the flash itself that are not at default values will not be changeable by the transmitter.
Beyond making sure the X2T-C transmitter and the X1R-C receiver are on the same channel and group, don't forget to make sure the "Wireless ID" number on both the X2T-C and X1R-C are set to the same value.

The 580EX is going to be problematic if you want more than simple manual triggering.  Godox's add-on radio receiver, the X1R-C only really works with full compatibility with the 580EX II and later models of Canon speedlites that can do camera menu communication with Digic 4 and later Canon bodies.
With the 430EX or 580EX (or earlier EX or EZ models) that cannot do this menu communication, you can remotely fire the camera, but power control, particularly in M, may not work.
In general, getting a Godox speedlight like a TT685 II-C to go with a Godox transmitter would offer better compatibility and more function.
To add a legacy OEM flash into any 3rd-party radio flash scheme, you are going to have to find a matching add-on radio receiver with a hotshoe (if one exists in the system) to attach to the foot of the flash to remotely control it from a Godox transmitter on the hotshoe of the camera. In this case, the X1R-C receiver or the Flashpoint R2 SPT (manual only).
The basic steps for using any flash off-camera pretty much remain the same:

Attach the receiver to the foot of the flash.
Attach the transmitter to the hotshoe of the camera.
Turn on the camera, then the transmitter.
Turn on the flash, then the receiver.
Set the transmitter and receiver to use the same channel.
Ensure both transmitter and receiver use the same ID setting.
Assign a group to the receiver.
Adjust the settings for that group on the transmitter.

Note. You don't need a Godox X2T to remotely fire/control the 580EX off-camera from an 80D.  The pop-up flash on the 80D can be used as an optical (light-signal) wireless master unit to the 580EX, if it's set into Canon's "smart" optical slave mode (slide the switch above the foot to SLAVE).  You would have TTL, HSS, and remote power/group control over it, though possibly only in TTL mode, not M.
